# ¿Cómo ordenar alfabéticamente un ol con librería pdfkmake?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Estoy intentando establecer que el tipo de ordenamiento de la lista `ol` sea por letras, (atributo type='A') para la creación de un fichero PDF con la librería pdfmake, pero no lo logro, cómo se realiza con esta librería?

> Esto es lo que no funciona e intento realizar sobre todos los ol

```
letra: {
    list-style-type: upper-roman
}
```

pdfmake: [enlace](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html)

### Código

```
var dd = {
content: [
    { text: 'Pregunta 1', style: 'header' },
    {
        ol: [
            'RESPUESTA A',
            'RESPUESTA B',
            'RESPUESTA C',
            'RESPUESTA D'
        ],
        style: 'letra'
    }
],
styles: {
    header: {
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 15
    },
    letra: {
        list-style-type: upper-roman
    }
},
defaultStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
}

}
```

Comment: ¿te refieres a orden alfabetico?

Comment: Si, en orden alfabético ahora edito el título

Comment: quiza seria mejor poner un ejemplo desordenado pues ya esta ordenado y se pierde la idea.

Comment: Está ordenado numéricamente busco alfabéticamente, ese es mi problema que no consigo cambiarle el tipo de 'simbolo'

Comment: el OL esta ordenado alfabeticamente y no hay (o no veo) ningun atributo type.

Comment: @dddenis tú controlas la variable dd, ¿por qué no ordenas sus valores directamente?

Comment: para redondear, puedes poner un ejemplo de como seria ordenado y como desordenado... asi no me queda la duda sobre la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre la primera parte de tu pregunta:

> > Esto es lo que no funciona e intento realizar sobre todos los ol
>
> ```
> letra: {
>     list-style-type: upper-roman
> }
> ```

Eso no te funciona por dos motivos:

1. Los índices no pueden llevar guiones si van sin comillas
2. El valor `upper-roman` es una cadena y debe ir entrecomillada

La solución es simple: entrecomillar tanto el índice/llave, como el valor:

```
 letra: {
     "list-style-type": "upper-roman"
 }
```

Y entonces ya será un objeto válido.

---

Sobre la ordenación, @rnd te ha dejado una buena respuesta; yo voy a poner una alternativa un poco diferente. La idea es la siguiente:

1. Atraviesa el objeto buscando listas en el contenido
2. Si encuentra una lista

   1. Comprueba si hay un propiedad `sort` (creada por nosotros, no propia de pdfmake)
   2. Ordena la lista si la propiedad `sort` existe y es `true`.

El método en sí es similar al que propone @rnd, lo único es que es más genérico y te permite procesar más de una lista, además de que no necesitas conocer la posición de la lista para implementarlo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería. Cópialo al [*playground* de pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) y podrás ver el resultado (la primera lista se ordena, la segunda no):

```
var dd = {
  content: [
    { text: 'Pregunta 1', style: 'header' },
    {
      ol: [
        'RESPUESTA C',
        'RESPUESTA B',
        'RESPUESTA A',
        'RESPUESTA D'
      ],
      style: 'letra',
      sort: true
    },
     { text: 'Pregunta 2', style: 'header' },
    {
      ol: [
        'RESPUESTA C',
        'RESPUESTA B',
        'RESPUESTA A',
        'RESPUESTA D'
      ],
      style: 'letra'
    }
  ],
  styles: {
    header: {
      bold: true,
      fontSize: 15
    },
    letra: {
      "list-style-type": "upper-roman"
    }
  },
  defaultStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  }
}

// ésta es la parte encargada de buscar y ordenar la listas
dd.content.forEach(function(element, index) {
    if ("ol" in element) {
    if (element.sort||false) {
      element.ol = element.ol.sort();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: wow, no la había visto hasta ahora, así se enseña.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes ordenar el array antes de pasarlo al PFD maker...

ejemplo.

```js
var dd = {
  content: [ {
    text: 'Pregunta 1',
    style: 'header'
  }, {
    // fijate que las desordene
    ol: [
      'RESPUESTA B',
      'RESPUESTA D',
      'RESPUESTA A',
      'RESPUESTA C'
    ],
    style: 'letra'
  }],
  styles: {
    header: {
      bold: true,
      fontSize: 15
    },
    letra: {
      "list-style-type": "upper-roman"
    }
  },
  defaultStyle: {
    fontSize: 12,
  }
};

// asi la ordenas alfabeticamente
console.log(
  dd.content[1].ol.sort()
);

// luego reemplazas
 
dd.content[1].ol = dd.content[1].ol.sort();
```

Comment: Fuiste más rápido :P